# Absolute Path with one backslash not working in Vs Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Adding copy pasted absolute paths into VS Code editor such as `"C:\Users\username\Desktop\filename.txt"` does not work, it throws the 'The system cannot find the file specified.' error.
But instead `"C:\\Users\\username\\Desktop\\filename.txt"` does work. How can I make it read the copy pasted absolute path so I don't have to modify it every time?

Comment: Where do you paste it? Into the editor?

Comment: @MarkusMeyer yes, into the editor

Comment: Is there any existing code in the editor?

Comment: Yes, ```"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "F:\\GitBash\\Git\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe"``` this was for setting up Git, in ```settings.json``` file inside VS Code editor.

Comment: And this is the Dart code where I came across this problem again ```File("C:\\Users\\username\\Desktop\\delucru.txt").readAsString().then(print);```.

Comment: ok, and how is this related to `Visual Studio`? Only VS Code has such a a setting file

Comment: @MarkusMeyer I thought it was a problem with ```Visual Studio``` because I always have to refactor the Path with two \\.

Comment: you are editing a settings file and you have to Escape the backslash to get a literal backslash, the same with a string in your code, backslash with some characters has special meaning like TAB if combined with t `\t`

Comment: if you need a literal backslash in a regex in a setting you need 4 backslashes in the file

Comment: Thank you very much, I understand what you mean, I forgot about this rule